# Datapump not working in RAC environment

Tags: oracle, export, expdp

Some minutes ago I've tried to do an export but I get the following error (AIX system):

```
Additional information: 3
ORA-31693: Table data object "XX"."TABLE_NAME" failed to load/unload and is being skipped due to error:
ORA-31617: unable to open dump file "/dir/back/dump/dump_xx_04.dmp" for write
ORA-19505: failed to identify file "/dir/back/dump/dump_xx_04.dmp"
ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
IBM AIX RISC System/6000 Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

What could the reason for this behaviour be?

I've read in some blog that using just `parallel=N` without `%U` that the export is actually slower. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, it could run slower because the parallel threads can't all write to the same file at the same time and they pile up waiting for each other. What was the exact command that you used?

Comment: expdp userid=xx/xx directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR_xx dumpfile=dump_xx_%U.dmp schemas=xx logfile=dump_RM.log parallel=4 flashback_time=systimestamp

Comment: I should also have asked what version of Oracle you are using, and if it was a RAC or stand-alone configuration?

Comment: It's 11.2 RAC I found this doc, maybe can be it right? Doc ID 1597395.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem.

The doc ID 1597395.1 says:

> The problem occurs when Datapump Export is being performed on a
>   multi-node RAC where the dumpfile destination is not shared to all
>   nodes for access.  Since multiple nodes will be running the Datapump
>   job, ALL nodes must have access to the mount point where the dump file
>   will be written.

So I've just used the parameter `cluster=n` in export to resolve it.